# Getting error "invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting an error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/pawno/domains/rgl.lt/public_html/vvp/index.php on line 96

Line 96 == 20 in this excerpt.

CONFIG PAGE:

```
<?php
$databasehost = "localhost";
$databasename = "db";
$databaseuser = "user";
$databasepass = "pass";

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename",
      $databaseuser, $databasepass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Nepavyko prisijungti prie duomenų bazės. 
      Praneškite apie šią klaidą administracijai. 
      Klaidos kodas: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

INDEX PAGE:

```
<div class = "vvpbutton">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players 
      WHERE Vardas = ".$_SESSION[ 'Vardas' ]."";
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row)
    {?>
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» PATIRTIES TAŠKAI: <?=$row['Xp']?> XP</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» IEŠKOMUMAS: 0 žvaigžd.</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» PASLAUGŲ VALIUTA: 0 kred.</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» ADMIN: Yra ( 2015.02.25 )</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» VIP: Nėra</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» PINIGAI RANKOSE: 0 €</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» PINIGAI BANKE: 0 €</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» DARBAS: Policininkas</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» UŽBLOKUOTAS: Ne</button>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You should include your code in your question.

Comment: there is a pastebin, i don't get this code system :D

Comment: You should setup PDO to throw exceptions so that it will tell you what is wrong with your (failing...) query. Is the `Vardas` column an integer? If not you need to quote it or - even better- use a prepared statement.

Comment: `foreach()` expects an array, its more like you are trying to use a string or something else. Make sure that `$db->query($sql)` is an array before trying to use it with the **foreach()** function

Comment: @jeroen: the column name literally translates to English as "*first name*", so there's a pretty good guess it's not an integer. Can you expand your comment to an answer, or provide a link to an existing one?

Answer (score 2):

That mark-up is just bad bro, You don't know the return value of `$db->query($sql)`, so why are you assuming its an array?

First store the return data of the query in a variable;

`$rows = $db->query($sql);`

Then check if its an array before trying to use it as one;

```
if(is_array($rows)){
  //do something if the return data is an array
  foreach ($rows as $row){?>
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» PATIRTIES TAŠKAI: <?=$row['Xp']?> XP</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» IEŠKOMUMAS: 0 žvaigžd.</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» PASLAUGŲ VALIUTA: 0 kred.</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» ADMIN: Yra ( 2015.02.25 )</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» VIP: Nėra</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» PINIGAI RANKOSE: 0 €</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» PINIGAI BANKE: 0 €</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» DARBAS: Policininkas</button><br />
    <button type="button" class="vvpbuttonss btn btn-danger">» UŽBLOKUOTAS: Ne</button>
  <?php }
} else {?> <p>The provided data isn't an array</p> <?php }
```

Though I have a nagging feeling that your return data isn't an array.